AG GRID upgrade31 from 27.0
When upgrading from an older version, we're unable to locate the source files to address the majority of breaking changes and deprecations.
When upgrading from version 27.0.0 to 31.1.0 in the package.json file:
"ag-grid-community": "27.0.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "27.0.0",
"ag-grid-react": "27.0.0"
to
"ag-grid-community": "31.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "31.1.0",
"ag-grid-react": "31.1.0"
C:\SRC\myapp>npx @ag-grid-devtools/cli@31.1 migrate --from=27.0.0 --dry-run
Migrating from version 27.0.0 to version 31.1.0...
Running 2 codemods:

31.0.0
31.1.0
Processing .eslintrc.js
Processing src\common\aggridConstant.ts
Processing src\common\aggridWideSpanCellRenderer.tsx
Processing src\common\components\draggableFAB.tsx
Processing src\common\components\globalLoader\globalLoader.tsx
Processing src\common\components\threeStateToggleSwitch.tsx
Processing src\common\components\uploadComponent\multiFileUpload.tsx
Processing src\common\components\uploadComponent\uploadFile.tsx
Processing src\common\confirmDeleteModal.tsx
Processing src\common\constant.ts
Processing src\common\contractCasesConstant.ts
Processing src\common\currencySymbolMap.ts
Processing src\common\customDropdownFilter.tsx
Processing src\common\customFloatingFilter.tsx
Processing src\common\customLoadingCellRenderer.tsx

C:\SRC\myapp>
When upgrading from an older version in my project, I'm unable to identify the breaking changes and deprecations.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
